# Focus or Autofocus in Input Text doesn't work in Firefox 16.0.2

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, iframe, fancybox

I want to focus on a input text after page loads/starts. This is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="tags">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="getId()" />
    <input type="text" name="tag" id="tag" autofocus="autofocus"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" name="add" />
</form>
```

I tried jQuery but it doesn't work on Firefox:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#tag").focus();
});
```

This is a window that opens as Iframe using Fancybox. This is my Fancybox function:

```
jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type: "iframe",
    width: 640,
    height: 320,
    afterClose : function() {
        location.reload();
        return;
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        jQuery('.fancybox-iframe').find('#tag').focus();
    }
});
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you!

Comment: `tag` doesn't exist as an ID...

Comment: what is getId() doing there - could you get rid of it? and try again and have you made sure that jquery file is included at the top or bottom of the page etc.?

Comment: I corrected the explanation ahren, I'm using ID. Thanks.

Comment: Even after erasing getId() the problem persists. Jquery file was included.

Comment: Hey, it seems that you are using fancybox v2.x and `onComplete` IS NOT a valid API option for that version ... use `afterShow` instead

Comment: ... additionally (if using v2.x) the correct selector is `jQuery(".fancybox-iframe")`

Comment: @JFK I edited my function, you were right, I'm using V 2.x (See what I did, correct me if I'm wrong). Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a Fancybox/Iframe communication problem. When I test the file alone it works combining autofucs and document.getElementById("tag").focus; This is my Source [link](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15020/why-doesnt-autofocus-autofocus-work-in-mozilla-firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I omitted contents() in my answer. In Fancybox v2.x it would be something like:

```
jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox({
type: "iframe",
width: 640,
height: 320,
afterClose : function() {
    location.reload();
    return;
},
afterShow: function() {
    jQuery('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('#tag').focus()
}
});
```

Thank you JFK and Fabrício Matté.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 //change this selector:
$('yourselector').fancybox({
    onComplete: function() {
        $('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('#tag').focus();
    }
});
```

[API reference](http://fancybox.net/api)

As you're loading the content into an `iframe`, jQuery will not find its contents with the standard `$(selector)`. [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method will though.

`#fancybox-frame` is the default ID of the fancybox `iframe`. The `onComplete` callback fires when the content is loaded.

---

After some testing, it seems that the `onComplete` handler fires too earlier. Using a timeout is an ugly solution, so adapting your loaded page should be a better option:

```
<form method="post" action="tags">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="getId()" />
    <input type="text" name="tag" id="tag" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" name="add" />
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById('tag').focus();
</script>
```

As it is loaded into an iframe, the script will be executed normally and focus the input element as it should.

Comment: I guess my selector is ".fancybox" right? this is the function that calls the iframe.

Comment: Yeah should be it. Any luck yet? I'm trying to make a fiddle but if you post some example markup and how you're calling it it'll help a bit.

Comment: @82din I've been experimenting with the `onComplete` callback and it seems bugged (fires too early). However check out the answer update, it should be more clean (make sure to Ctrl+F5/disable cache).

Comment: My friend, as crazy as it sounds, document.getElementById('tag').focus(); doesn't work either on Firefox, at least in my example.

Comment: Did you put it inside a script tag below the form? I copypasted your code and it worked on my Firefox. A very last approach would be setting a [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) handler to the `#fancybox-frame`, but that'd be just extra hackish.

Comment: I did Fabricio, below the closing form tag.

Comment: That's weird. Try right-clicking in the iframe and choose This Frame > Reload Frame, that usually helps if it's a caching issue. It seems to work for me. Too sleepy atm, I can take another look at it tomorrow, best of luck meanwhile. `=]`

Answer (score 0):

you have mentioned id "tag" which doesn't exist

```
<form method="post" action="tags">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="getId()" />
    <input type="text" name="tag" id = "tag" autofocus="autofocus"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" name="add" />
</form>
```

Comment: I did Jatin, I just added it to the form few seconds ago.